# TensorBoard legend and label axis

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

Hi  Is it possible to have a legend and axis labels in TensorBoard? if so how? the last post regarding similar question was raised in 2017. I am wondering if there has been an update since then  Thanks a lot

Comment: Well... possible, it is; but you'd have to change the source code... from the current API, you can't.